# RevoScaleR package for Microsoft R Open 3.5.3

Tags: r, revoscaler

I've tried to install the `RevoScaleR` package within Microsoft R Open 3.5.3 but I get the message

> "package ‘RevoScaleR’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)"

which I suppose is clear enough. Is there any way around this? Or will I just have to drop back to an earlier version of MRO to get it to work? I need to use the `rxGlm()` function because the standard `glm()` function won't cope with the data I'm working with (size and complexity).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft R Open does not include the proprietary R libraries. You can get these for free by using Microsoft R Client instead, which is Microsoft R Open with the addition of RevoScaleR built in. This package is not open source and cannot be installed into a regular R installation.

You can read more about the Client version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-client/what-is-microsoft-r-client

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh ok - thank you. Problem solved! I had to do a PC rebuild recently and I've installed MS R Open (instead of MS R Client as previously) by mistake. Easily fixed.